comma separated information in one cell
I have a dataset in R with messy data where each person's test information is stored in separate corrosponding columns: test_name, test_result, and test_status. All three columns contain comma-separated values for each test if more than one test was performed. I want to extract the individual tests, their corresponding results, and statuses for each person in the most efficient way possible. My end goal is to be able to pull the different tests and their results and status for each person. This is a sample of the data.
dput(tb_sample_10)
structure(list(test_name = c("TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,AFB Smear", 
"AFB Smear,Sensitivity,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status,Culture", 
"Culture,AFB Smear,Sensitivity,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status", 
"AFB Smear", "Culture,AFB Smear,Sensitivity,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status", 
"Culture,AFB Smear,Sensitivity,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status", 
"AFB Smear,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status", "Culture,AFB Smear,Sensitivity,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status", 
"AFB Smear,TB Direct PCR & RIF Status", "TB Direct PCR & RIF Status,Culture"
), test_result = c("MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected,No AFB Seen", 
"OTHER,Not Required,MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected,Not Required,No Growth", 
"Positive,No AFB Seen,Processed,Rejected,MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected (MTBC)", 
"AFB+", "Positive,OTHER,Processed,MTB Not Detected,Not Required", 
"Positive,AFB+,Not Required,MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected,Not Required", 
"No AFB Seen,MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected", "No Growth,No AFB Seen,Not Required,MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected,Not Required", 
"No AFB Seen,MTB Not Detected", "MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected,Positive"
), test_status = c("Final,Final", "Final,Final,Final,Final,Final", 
"Final,Final,Final,Final,Final", "Final", "Final,Final,Final,Final,Final", 
"Final,Final,Final,Final,Final", "Final,Final", "Final,Final,Final,Final,Final", 
"Final,Final", "Final,Final")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



You can use str_split, enframe, and unnest to separate the three entities. Then, combine these using inner_join.
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(stringr)

tests <- str_split(tb_sample_10$test_name, pattern=",") |>
  enframe(name="id", value="test") |>
  unnest(test) |>
  mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=id) |>
  select(id, seq, test)

results <- str_split(tb_sample_10$test_result, pattern=",") |>
  enframe(name="id", value="result") |>
  unnest(result) |>
  mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=id)

statuses <- str_split(tb_sample_10$test_status, pattern=",") |>
  enframe(name="id", value="status") |>
  unnest(status) |>
  mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=id)

Reduce(inner_join, list(tests, results, statuses))
# A tibble: 34 x 5
      id   seq test                         result                                     status
   <int> <int> <chr>                        <chr>                                      <chr> 
 1     1     1 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected Final 
 2     1     2 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                                Final 
 3     2     1 AFB Smear                    OTHER                                      Final 
 4     2     2 Sensitivity                  Not Required                               Final 
 5     2     3 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected Final 
 6     2     4 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status Not Required                               Final 
 7     2     5 Culture                      No Growth                                  Final 
 8     3     1 Culture                      Positive                                   Final 
 9     3     2 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                                Final 
10     3     3 Sensitivity                  Processed                                  Final 
# i 24 more rows


Using tidyverse functions, as per the question tag:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tb_sample_10 %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(ID = ID,
            names = list(strsplit(test_name, ",")),
            results = list(strsplit(test_result, ",")),
            statuses = list(strsplit(test_status, ","))) %>%
unnest(cols = c(names, results, statuses)) %>%
unnest(cols = c(names, results, statuses))

# A tibble: 34 × 4
      ID names                        results                                           statuses
   <int> <chr>                        <chr>                                             <chr>
 1     1 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected        Final
 2     1 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                                       Final
 3     2 AFB Smear                    OTHER                                             Final
 4     2 Sensitivity                  Not Required                                      Final
 5     2 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected        Final
 6     2 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status Not Required                                      Final
 7     2 Culture                      No Growth                                         Final
 8     3 Culture                      Positive                                          Final
 9     3 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                                       Final
10     3 Sensitivity                  Processed                                         Final
11     3 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   Rejected                                          Final
12     3 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected (MTBC) Final
13     4 AFB Smear                    AFB+                                              Final
14     5 Culture                      Positive                                          Final
15     5 AFB Smear                    OTHER                                             Final
16     5 Sensitivity                  Processed                                         Final
17     5 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Not Detected                                  Final
18     5 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status Not Required                                      Final
19     6 Culture                      Positive                                          Final
20     6 AFB Smear                    AFB+                                              Final
# ℹ 14 more rows


Note that I created an ID column, just to keep track of things.  You might have it already on you data, or go without it anyway.

You can do this with tidyr::separate_longer_delim(). This was released in tidyr 1.3.0 (January 2023):

The biggest feature of this release is a new, experimental family of functions for separating string columns

This function is marked with lifecycle experimental, meaning there is no promise for long-term stability. However, it has been around for over a year and it seems designed for exactly the case you have here.
I've also added an id column which isn't necessary for separating the rows, but may be helpful to keep track of which of the original 10 rows each of the now 34 rows relates to.
tb_sample_10 |>
    dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::row_number(), .before = test_name) |>
    tidyr::separate_longer_delim(
        cols = dplyr::starts_with("test"),
        delim = ","
    )

# # A tibble: 34 × 4
#       id test_name                    test_result                    test_status
#    <int> <chr>                        <chr>                          <chr>      
#  1     1 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance… Final      
#  2     1 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                    Final      
#  3     2 AFB Smear                    OTHER                          Final      
#  4     2 Sensitivity                  Not Required                   Final      
#  5     2 TB Direct PCR & RIF Status   MTB Detected / RIF Resistance… Final      
#  6     2 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status Not Required                   Final      
#  7     2 Culture                      No Growth                      Final      
#  8     3 Culture                      Positive                       Final      
#  9     3 AFB Smear                    No AFB Seen                    Final      
# 10     3 Sensitivity                  Processed                      Final      
# # ℹ 24 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Using data.table, split columns 1,2, and 3 on comma, and add as new row, note that I am adding column I to keep track of rows IDs.
tb_sample_10[, lapply(.SD, \(i) unlist(tstrsplit(i, ","))), by = .I, .SDcols = 1:3 ]

#        I                    test_name                                test_result test_status
#    <int>                       <char>                                     <char>      <char>
# 1:     1   TB Direct PCR & RIF Status MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected       Final
# 2:     1                    AFB Smear                                No AFB Seen       Final
# 3:     2                    AFB Smear                                      OTHER       Final
# 4:     2                  Sensitivity                               Not Required       Final
# 5:     2   TB Direct PCR & RIF Status MTB Detected / RIF Resistance Not Detected       Final
# 6:     2 TB Indirect PCR & RIF Status                               Not Required       Final
# 7:     2                      Culture                                  No Growth       Final
# 8:     3                      Culture                                   Positive       Final
# 9:     3                    AFB Smear                                No AFB Seen       Final
#10:     3                  Sensitivity                                  Processed       Final

